# fetchUserRecord for frontend login giving typo3 error

Tags: authentication, typo3

I am working in typo3 10. When trying to fetch the frontend user record from my custom extension, it is throwing error as
[image]

My code is

```
public function getFeUser( string $email )
{
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->checkPid = 0;
    $info = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getAuthInfoArray();
    $info['db_user']['username_column'] = 'email';
    $user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserRecord($info['db_user'], $email);
    return $user;
}
```

Has anyone faced an error while working in typo3 10?

Thank you

Comment: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5/Deprecation-86466-AbstractUserAuthentication-fetchUserRecord.html

Comment: Directly called the fetchUserRecord method from AbstractAuthenticationService into my custom extension.

Comment: `* @deprecated since TYPO3 v9, will be removed in TYPO3 v10.0` - https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/9.5/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Authentication/AbstractUserAuthentication.php#L1608

Comment: I have used the method from https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/master/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Authentication/AbstractAuthenticationService.php#L126. Does it create any issues?